# Jquery Mobile change page based on a condition

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have 2 Jquery Mobile pages (Login and Home).  When the user first launches the application (phonegap) the system check for a local storage variable ('ses_already_login).  If the variable is set then the system should not show the login page instead it should show the home page.  If the variable is not set then it should show the login page.

Both login and home page contains a header and footer with some form controls which are loaded dynamically using jQuery.

I am doing something like below and I see a blank grey screen.  The condition gets through and could see the alert message after that I goes to a blank screen.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#pg_login",function(){
  if(checkAlreadyLogin()){
    alert('I am inside');
    $.mobile.changePage("#pg_home");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I also aware that changePage is deprecated.  So, can someone help me how I can redirect/change to the home page.

Comment: You haven't described what is not working in your current solution.  How does your existing logic fail?

Comment: @Kolban - The logic is not failing.  The condition becomes true and then I see a blank page.

Comment: It might be that the jQuery Mobile semantics don't allow you to attempt to change pages during callbacks in the page change life cycle.  What about having logic that runs at the initialization of your page to determine which page to show first and then change to it directly as opposed to in a page change lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

You need to use `pagecontainerbeforechange` in that case not any other event. Because at this stage, you can alter `toPage` property to redirect user to any page you want.

That event *always* fires twice and returns `toPage` which holds either `url` (string) or jQuery `object` of target page. However, on first run it returns a jQuery `object` twice. When it fires for the first time, you have to make sure that `toPage` is an `object` and `absUrl` is `undefined`, in addition to your *condition*.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function(e, data) {
  if(typeof data.toPage == "object" && typeof data.absUrl == "undefined" && !condition) {
    data.toPage = $("#login"); /* change to page with ID "login" */
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tJSctJHV4W5mDfZmClMV?p=info)**

---

#### Solution 2:

Another solution is to listen to `mobileinit` event to check whether user is logged in or not, and then change the position of target page to make "first" page in DOM.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function (e, data) {
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false; /* optional - stop auto-initalization */
    if (!condition) {
        $(function () {
            $("#login").prependTo("body"); /* make "login" page first child of "pagecontainer" (body by default) */
            $.mobile.initializePage(); /* optional - manual initialization */
        });
    }
});
```

You can delay *auto-initialization* of the framework if you want, however, jQuery functions `.prependTo` should be wrapped in `$(function() {});` or `.ready()` because `mobileinit` fires before jQuery library is ready.

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ik7oz5tWsl2IWMWF5Df4?p=preview)**

Comment: actually I coded my app in the way it first loads the login screen and then it goes to the home screen.  But what I understand from your code is the other way round, which shows the home page first and if the session is not loaded then show the login screen.  It makes sense.  I changed the code w.r.t Solution 1 and it works.  Thanks

Comment: @Malaiselvan you're welcome :) I assume the second solution is less code and it fires one time only. `pagecontainerbeforechange` will keep firing upon navigating. It's your call anyway, do what you see best :)